# Combining INDEX(MATCH()) with ARRAYFORMULA() fails

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas, index-match

I need a formula for the `VariantAttribute` column, which fills in the `ProductAttribute` value based on the first 4 characters of the `VariantID`

Desired result:

| ProductID | ProductAttribute |  | VariantID | VariantAttribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | blue |  | ABCD-xx | blue |
| BCDE | black |  | ABCD-yy | blue |
| CDEF | orange |  | BCDE-vv | black |
| DEFG | blue |  | BCDE-ww | black |
|  |  |  | CDEF-uu | orange |
|  |  |  | DEFG-zz | blue |
|  |  |  | ABCD-uu | blue |

I tried to combine `ARRAYFORMULA()` with `INDEX(MATCH())`but failed, obviously because I'm not able to specify a search range within `ARRAYFORMULA()`

[image]

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: INDEX MATCH does not work with ARRAYFORMULA().  You have to rewrite it as a vlookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dash ("-") is consistent.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,VLOOKUP(INDEX(SPLIT(D2:D,"-"),,1),A:B,2,0))
```